# HTML php syntax bug/error

Tags: php, html, syntax

I'm trying to make simple code syntax highlight. I'm using Prism (prismjs.com) But when i'm write php for example:

```
<pre>
    <code class="language-markup">
       <?php echo "it not works"; ?>
    </code>
</pre>
```

> echo "it not works"; ?>

not print's it works like php, how can i fix it? Thanks in advance

Sorry for my bad english, I wan't to print that php code, not to launch/.. it, I wan't to write  code and it must prints in code tag, not launch or something like that

Comment: Do you mean it outputs `it not works` and you want it to output `<?php echo "it not works"; ?>`?

Comment: @chris85, yep i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert the PHP opening/closing tags to entities it will output that PHP content.

```
<pre>
    <code class="language-markup">
       &lt;?php echo "it not works"; ?&gt;
    </code>
</pre>
```

Demo: https://eval.in/410033

An alternative would be just making the file `.html`, unless you have your server configured to server `.html` as `php` as well.

Comment: Alright. Please mark this as accepted when the required time has passed, http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer.